# Animation issue after calling notifyitemchanged

Tags: android, android-animation, android-glide

I've an `ImageView` in which image is loaded using **Glide**. When I've performed the **like** action then Notify the recycler view adapter using `notifyItemChanged(position)`. It causes the blinks the image 2 times.
Can anyone help me here.

This portion of code is executed when the `notifyItemChanged(position)` is called:

```
    Glide.with(mContext)
    .load(mainImage)
    .placeholder(R.color.grey_light)
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
    .into(listItemHolder.mSingleAttachmentImage);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: got solution ??

Comment: Crosslink: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1599

Comment: The double-blink is suspicious, @danypata's solution should have removed one of those blinks. Try [LoggingListener](https://github.com/TWiStErRob/glide-support/blob/master/src/glide3/java/com/bumptech/glide/supportapp/utils/LoggingListener.java) to see what sizes Glide observes. Since you didn't change the image, only the "like-state", the Glide should be sync and the view size shouldn't change.

Answer (score 3):

Solution 1 ：

```java
ItemAnimator animator = mRecyclerView.getItemAnimator();
if (animator instanceof SimpleItemAnimator) {
    ((SimpleItemAnimator) animator).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
}
```

> ref https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1599

---

Solution 2 ：

`notifyItemChanged(int position)` > `notifyItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount)` > `notifyItemRangeChanged(positionStart, itemCount, null)` ;

```java
/**
         * Notify any registered observers that the item at <code>position</code> has changed with an
         * optional payload object.
         *
         * <p>This is an item change event, not a structural change event. It indicates that any
         * reflection of the data at <code>position</code> is out of date and should be updated.
         * The item at <code>position</code> retains the same identity.
         * </p>
         *
         * <p>
         * Client can optionally pass a payload for partial change. These payloads will be merged
         * and may be passed to adapter's {@link #onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder, int, List)} if the
         * item is already represented by a ViewHolder and it will be rebound to the same
         * ViewHolder. A notifyItemRangeChanged() with null payload will clear all existing
         * payloads on that item and prevent future payload until
         * {@link #onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder, int, List)} is called. Adapter should not assume
         * that the payload will always be passed to onBindViewHolder(), e.g. when the view is not
         * attached, the payload will be simply dropped.
         *
         * @param position Position of the item that has changed
         * @param payload Optional parameter, use null to identify a "full" update
         *
         * @see #notifyItemRangeChanged(int, int)
         */
        public final void notifyItemChanged(int position, Object payload) {
            mObservable.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, 1, payload);
        }
```

notice `@param payload Optional parameter, use null to identify a "full" update`

you can use `notifyItemChanged(position,position)` and do changeView in `RecyclerView.Adapter.onBindViewHolder()`

Comment: solution 1. worked for me, I was facing the same problem like in the question. I have a view that has ImageView in the center and a like button when i click like button first time it works fine, and then liking the very next item and if this item does'nt has an image loaded in its imageview then glide was loading the image of the previously like Item and this fixed my Issue thanks buddy

Answer (score 1):

I think the blink of the image is caused by the `ItemAnimator` of the `RecylerView`. I had the same issue and I solved it by adding the default animator and telling the recycler view to reuse the view holder for the animations. Something like this:

```
theRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator() {
        @Override
        public boolean canReuseUpdatedViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canReuseUpdatedViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull List<Object> payloads) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

In this way the RecyclerView can use the same ViewHolder and won't create another one when notifyItemChange is called.

Comment: Not works for me. I think it's glide problem. Because when using the Picasso library the blinking issue is not occured.

Comment: @danypata check out [Wizard's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42605415/253468) for an alternative without creating a new class.