# RecylerView changing single parameter in a row?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide, notifydatasetchanged

I have RecyclerView, single row includes text, image. After loading data, in a button click i want to change text without reloading image of the row. I tried using notifyItemChanged(position). But it makes image reloading.. Am using glide for loading images, so when i use notifyItemChanged(position), row flickering occurs

Comment: Instead you can disable flickering...

Comment: I meant you can prevent row from flickering...

Comment: how ? it's not row.. flickering occurs in image

Comment: in Glide, while creating the request. add `.dontAnimate` option

Comment: Crosslink: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1599

Answer (score 2):

Whole row will be reloaded once you call `notifyItemChanged()`
Two options:
1) Disable default recyclerview item animation

```
ItemAnimator animator = recyclerView.getItemAnimator();
if (animator instanceof SimpleItemAnimator) {
  ((SimpleItemAnimator) animator).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
}
```

2) Use placeholder while loading an image

> Check out this [Glide official link](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/527) to fix the problem with
>   placeholder

Comment: The animator should help, that's a good one Wizard! However, I don't think the second option is applicable here, because the image stays the same; which means it'll be loaded from memory-cache synchronously and hence the `.placeholder` won't be used, nor any animation will be played by Glide.

Comment: Oh..yes. Exactly.